# How to custom set a user list to be displayed in FriendPickerFragment

Tags: android, facebook

I'm working on an application where I use the Facebook SDK. I've integrated Facebook SDK in my app. I'm trying to display Facebook friends for the logged in user. I've would not like to show to the user all his Facebook friend, but only those who meet a certain criteria. I've managed to choose these Facebook friends, but not able to display them. 
Is there a way to custom display the Facebook friends ?
In my code, in order to fetch all Facebook users I user picker://friend uri. I've also tried to pass certain user IDs to that Uri, but with no success. Is there a was to pass Facebook Ids to picker://friend so I can display certain friends, or this direction is wrong?

Thanks in advance for you help.
Alex

Comment: The SDK includes a FriendPicker fragment where you can filter the results to only show the ones you want. Have a look at the BooleanOGSample for an example on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I've looked at this example, but it didn't work as I expected. I have my own class that holds facebook user data, including their IDs. I would like to display these users. The sample from facebook users the <UserGraph> interface. I think I juld from scratch a user listview...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I couldn't find anyone else who had tried to do this. I was able to subclass FriendPickerFragment to specify the user IDs, by overriding the graph request and its handler. It's a bit hacky but it seems to work.

```
// Has to be in this package so we can access package-private members on the superclass.
package com.facebook.widget;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.model.GraphObject;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Created by Derek on 1/11/2015.
 */
public class MyFriendPickerFragment extends FriendPickerFragment {
    private List<String> userIds;

    public void setUserIds(List<String> userIds) {
        this.userIds = userIds;
    }

    @Override
    Request getRequestForLoadData(Session session) {
        if (userIds == null) {
            return super.getRequestForLoadData(session);
        } else {
            return createRequest(extraFields, session);
        }
    }

    private Request createRequest(Set<String> extraFields, Session session) {
        Request request = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session, "", null);

        Set<String> fields = new HashSet<String>(extraFields);
        String[] requiredFields = new String[]{
                "id",
                "name"
        };
        fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(requiredFields));

        String pictureField = adapter.getPictureFieldSpecifier();
        if (pictureField != null) {
            fields.add(pictureField);
        }

        Bundle parameters = request.getParameters();
        parameters.putString("fields", TextUtils.join(",", fields));
        parameters.putString("ids", TextUtils.join(",", userIds));
        request.setParameters(parameters);

        return request;
    }

    @Override
    public void loadData(boolean forceReload) {
        if(userIds == null) {
            super.loadData(forceReload);
        } else {
            Request request = getRequestForLoadData(getSession());
            request.setCallback(
                    new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            if (response.getError() == null) {
                                Map<String, Object> map = response.getGraphObject().asMap();
                                final List<GraphUser> users = new ArrayList<>();
                                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)entry.getValue();
                                    GraphUser user = GraphObject.Factory.create(jsonObject, GraphUser.class);
                                    users.add(user);
                                }

                                adapter.changeCursor(new GraphObjectCursor<GraphUser>() {
                                    private int position = 0;

                                    @Override
                                    public boolean isFromCache() {
                                        return false;
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public boolean areMoreObjectsAvailable() {
                                        return position < getCount() - 1;
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public int getCount() {
                                        return users.size();
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public int getPosition() {
                                        return position;
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public boolean move(int offset) {
                                        return moveToPosition(position + offset);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public boolean moveToPosition(int newPosition) {
                                        if (newPosition >= 0 && newPosition < getCount()) {
                                            position = newPosition;
                                            return true;
                                        }
                                        return false;
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public boolean moveToFirst() {
                                        position = 0;
                                        return true;
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public boolean moveToLast() {
                                        position = getCount() - 1;
                                        return true;
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public boolean moveToNext() {
                                        return move(1);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public boolean moveToPrevious() {
                                        return move(-1);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public boolean isFirst() {
                                        return position == 0;
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public boolean isLast() {
                                        return position == getCount() - 1;
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public boolean isBeforeFirst() {
                                        return position < 0;
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public boolean isAfterLast() {
                                        return position >= getCount();
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public GraphUser getGraphObject() {
                                        return users.get(position);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void close() {
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public boolean isClosed() {
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
            request.executeAsync();
        }
    }
}
```